[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] when signingOut with NextAuth
I'm using Next.js.
So basically when I press the button to sign out the page reloads and I get this error in the console.
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error NetworkError when attempting to fetch    resource. 
Object { error: {…}, url: "/api/auth/csrf", message: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch     resource." }

For context this is my sidenav where the SignOutButton is:
import Link from 'next/link';
    import NavLinks from '@/app/ui/dashboard/nav-links';
    import AppointItLogo from '@/app/ui/appointIt-logo';
    import SignOutButton from '@/app/ui/dashboard/signout-button';

    export default async function SideNav() {
      return (
        <div className="flex h-full flex-col px-3 py-4 md:px-2">
          <Link
            className="mb-2 flex h-20 items-end justify-start rounded-md bg-blue-600 p-4 md:h-40"
            href="/home"
          >
            <div className="w-40 text-white md:w-40">
              <AppointItLogo />
            </div>
          </Link>
          <div className="flex grow flex-row justify-between space-x-2 md:flex-col 
           md:space-x-0 md:space-y-2">
            <NavLinks />
            <div className="hidden h-auto w-full grow rounded-md bg-gray-50 md:block"></div>
            <form>
              <SignOutButton />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }`

and this is the SignOutButton:
 "use client";

    import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";
    import { PowerIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';

    export default function SignOutButton() {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => signOut({
                redirect: true,
                callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/`
            })}
            className="flex h-[48px] w-full grow items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-md 
            bg-gray-50 p-3 text-sm font-medium hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600 
            md:flex-none md:justify-start md:p-2 md:px-3">
                <PowerIcon className="w-6" />
                <div className="hidden md:block">Sign Out</div>
            </button>
        );
    }`

To SignIn I'm using Credentials
I tried to go directly to localhost:3000/api/auth/csrf and the token gets returned so I don't understand why it isn't working
